# ArcGIS spatial joining problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I have two polygon layers, Land-use and Mesh.

I had this mesh layer in specific geometric way. Anyways, I want the mesh layer to have the landuse value of the maximum area it contains. Lets say that a polygon in the mesh contains three land use types (40% urban, 30% roads, 30% green areas). I want it to assign the value of urban because it has the biggest area.

I tried Spatial Join tool, but it did not give me what I was looking for. I used the (mode) as a Field Map of Join Features which should Use the value with the highest frequency but it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your two polygon layers as well as their attribute tables?